# How to solve Amplify backend-config.json does not exist issue

Tags: javascript, react-native, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I upgraded Amplify CLI, but I discovered in my `amplify/backend/backend-config.json` file has disappeared after taking a day to discovered that. Then I have tried running `amplify init` again with the options to continue with my existing environment or new environment, and I have tried both but still got the same error

> Error: File at path: 'C:\Users\BEN\documents\TinderClone\amplify\backend\backend-config.json' does not exist

What do I do to solve this error (to get the `backend-config.json` back).

[image]

Comment: `backend-config.jason` or `backend-config.json`?

Comment: Sorry, its backend-config.json

Comment: Does this happen after `git clone`? It's ignored by .gitignore file

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve this by using the amplify pull then navigating to the #current-cloud-backend and copying the file from there to the directory needed.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31646728)

Comment: What do you need to copy from #current-cloud-backend?  And what directory would need it?

Comment: I spoke with aws support about this that directory is the live environment used. So any files missing you can get from that directory.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by first upgrading amplify by amplify upgrade , then deleted amplify folder at the root folder of the project, and then pulled the amplify project by specifying appId and envName like following
amplify pull --appId xyz --envName dev
At the console some questions will appear and the important one ise 'Do you plan on modifying this backend?' , I chose Yes. And finally backend folder is added.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the issue after more than 24 hours of frustration looking for the solution.
In my C:\Users\BEN.amplify\bin I deleted the bin folder, and I upgraded the amplify CLI using:-
"curl -sL https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-cli/install-win -o install.cmd && install.cmd"
After the download and installation I restarted my system. That solved the backend-config.json does not exist issue.

I hope this works for you if you have this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
backend:
  phases:
   build:
      commands:
        - amplifyPush --simple
        - mv ./amplify/\#current-cloud-backend/backend-config.json ./
```